# How to create shape react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PmbS.png)

How to create curve under the circle element in react native

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read the FAQ section on asking great questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.  Some details to add would include what you have tried and what issues you ran into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom tab bar.

```
import Svg, { Path } from 'react-native-svg';

render(){
return(
...
<Svg width={WIDTH * 2} height={HEIGHT} style={styles.shadow}>
       <Path d={yourSvgPath} fill={'white'} stroke={white} />
</Svg>
)
}
```

Check this guy out to see how to get yourSvgPath

https://snack.expo.io/@git/github.com/wcandillon/can-it-be-done-in-react-native:bonuses/tabbar